# Automatically naming columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've created table like that:

```
sim_mcc_mnc   January    February  March  ....
   232-10      1234        4321    5678    (these numbers are number of records)
```

By naming each column manually:

```
SELECT 
    sim_mcc_mnc,
    sum(year(time_utc)=2013 AND month(time_utc)=1) as 'January 2013',
    sum(year(time_utc)=2013 AND month(time_utc)=2) as 'February 2013',
    sum(year(time_utc)=2013 AND month(time_utc)=3) as 'March 2013',
    sum(year(time_utc)=2013 AND month(time_utc)=4) as 'April 2013',
    ...
    ...
    ...

FROM
    table

where
    sim_mcc_mnc like '232-%' OR
    sim_mcc_mnc is null
GROUP BY 
    sim_mcc_mnc
;
```

My question is. Is there any possibility to name these columns automatically? I've tried to use `CONCAT`, but it seems to me that you can't use any function after `AS`.

Is there any other possibility?

Comment: @jarlh The real answer is: yes, this is possible, but you have to use a "stored procedure" for this.

Comment: Just output as rows, and handle the transformation in your presentation layer (e.g. a bit of PHP)

Comment: This is called a "pivot table" and it has numerous answers on Stack Overflow already, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/7674786/521799

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to do with the following line...

```
sum(year(time_utc)=2013 AND month(time_utc)=1) as 'January 2013',
```

This will return the number of rows which match, not the sum of the values...

To answer your question, you have two possibilities:

- using a stored procedure, which let you generate also the whole query
- renaming the column names in the application part, which is the easiest way.

Comment: I want to find number of records for specific month. The line should also look like this: sum(case when Month(time_utc) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as January,

Comment: I am beginning with MySQL, so I am not sure yet where is the border between MySQL and application part, because I find a lot of tasks easier to do afterwards in python than in MySQL. Especially these final data formatting in more human friendly form